# Cygwin difference between home and ~

Tags: cygwin

I'm new to CygWin but used to unix systems. Normally the ~ referes to a users home directory located in /home/usrname/. However in CygWin it points to my windows usr home - e.g. /cygdrive/c/Users/usrname. It also reads my .bashrc profile from here. However not my .ssh folder - which apparently is supposed to be under /home//.ssh.

Should ~ in cygwin rather point to /home/usrname? Which folder takes precedence if e.g. .bashrc is located in both locations?

I know I can change the db_home variable, however it seems weird to me that ~ and "home" is different from the beginning, and I would like to understand why to make an informed decision on wheter to use one or the other...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have the `HOME` environment variable set at the Windows level, which overrides the Cygwin mechanisms you refer to.

If I am right, you will find it set [in the System control panel](https://www.techjunkie.com/environment-variables-windows-10/). The fix is to un-set it. Cygwin itself will set `HOME` for you based on your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file settings.

Comment: True that. How come ssh looks for keys in /home then? :)

Comment: And is it unwise to use win-home as cygwin home? :)

Comment: @Hoof: sshd doesn't run under your user account, so it doesn't see your user's environment variables. It runs under a system account to do the privilege separation stuff you expect from sshd. And yes, overriding Cygwin the way you have is a problem, if only because it gives effects like you saw: sshd and bash don't agree on the same $HOME. The same basic problem affects other things, too, like cron.

Comment: Hm. I get that inconsistencies are bad and I've deleted my HOME variable from windows (was useful in gitbash). However setting the db_home variable to my windows home dir doesn't change the fact that sshd looks for keys in /home/%U - any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting since fixing the config? Have you modified `/etc/ssh*`?